How to Trigger an Event When Select2 Dropdown Value is Null in Vue.js
I'm working with a Vue.js application that uses the Select2 library for a dropdown in my reviseReport component. I have a NestedForm component where this dropdown is implemented. I need to trigger an event when the Select2 value becomes null.
Here are the relevant parts of my code:
nestedForm.Vue
<Select2
ref="restrictionSelect" 
v-model="Level1. name"
show-all
:settings="select2Settings"
size="small"
style="width: 100%; margin-left: 20px;" class="custom-font width-max-50" :display-key="false" :options="level10ptions"
@update:modelValue=" (value) =>
/>

revisedReport.vue
<nested-form 
ref="nestedForm"
: data="restrictions"
: source-options="sourceOptions"
@handLeChange="handleRestrictionChange"
/>

handleRestrictionChange({ Level, LevellId, levelId, levelId, value }}) {
if(this.hasRestrictionBlankError === true && isRestrictionExists){
LevelSchemaObj.id = '';
Level1SchemaObj. name ='';
const selectElement = this.$refs.nestedForm?. $refs?. restrictionSelect;
$(selectElement).val(''). trigger ('change');
 return;
}

const selectElement = this.$refs.nestedForm?. $refs?. restrictionSelect;
$(selectElement). val(''). trigger ('change');

I have tried this to trigger event when value is null but here it is not working..
Please help me with this.


maybe you can use a "watcher" on your model to handle the changes accordingly? https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers

jquery is not Vue friendly.  they are two different frameworks both trying to control the DOM.  mixing them should be avoided.

The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . What is ? If it's third-party component, this should be mentioned
